# How to position two divs horizontally next to each other whose one of them is collapsable?

Tags: html, css

Within my table-cell, which is displayed with a width of 100%, I am trying to display two divs horizontally next to each other. The first element should be collapsable and once collapsed, element 2 should overlap the empty space.

If the first element is visible it should take 25% of the space and the second one 75%.

Showing this situation in an image gives:

[image]

The above situation displays the first and second item. The one at the bottom just the second item with a width of 100%.

How can I get this done in CSS? (Where f.e. `display: none` will trigger the second item to expand it's width)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media-query for this:

```
.left-div {
  width: 25%;
}

.right-div {
  width: 75%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .left-div {
    width: 0px; || display: none;
  }
  .right-div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This will hide `left-div` and make `right-div` cover the whole width when the screen size is below 768px (tablet size).

Comment: I don't want collapsing based on the screen size. But I thought there is a way in css in which an item automatically takes the space over from a hidden element.

Comment: You can always change the rule when the width should change. A media query would make this automatic. When should this change happen?